# Compiler crash in simple macro manipulating a match statement

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-macros

```
def control(x: String): Option[String] = macro controlImpl
def controlImpl(c: Context)(x: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Option[String]] = {
    import c.universe._
    val result = x.tree match {
        case Match(expr, cases) =>
            val matchz = Match(q"""List("hello")""", cases)
            q"Some(List(5)).map{a => $matchz}"
        case a => a
    }
    c.Expr[Option[String]](result)
}
```

This macro crashes during macro expansion with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find proxy for val o7: Some in List(value o7, method apply, <$anon: Function1>, value f, method apply, <$anon: Function1>, method apply, <$anon: Function0>, value <local ApplicativeTest>, object ApplicativeTest, package scalaz, package <root>) (currentOwner= value one )
```

This is the macro application point:

```
val f = IdiomBracket.control {
    a.get match {
        case List(one) => one
        case _ => ""
    }
}
```

What is odd is that if you substitute `q"Some(List(5)).map{a => $matchz}"` with `q"Some($matchz)"` then the compiler crash goes away.

Answer (score 2):

"Simple macro" is an oxymoron.

The crash is in lambda lift, which indicates a bad symbol owner.

You can inspect the tree you produce with `-Ybrowse:typer`.

Consider what you'd like to produce:

```
class X {
  //def g = List("hello") match { case List(x) => x case _ => "" }
  def f = Some(List(5)).map{a => List("hello") match { case List(x) => x case _ => "" } }
}
```

The var in the case is owned by the anonfun you want to create:

```
Symbol: [has] value x
Symbol owner: value $anonfun
```

Your actual result:

```
Symbol: [has] value x
Symbol owner: value <local Controlled>
```

where `Controlled` is my sample enclosing object for your code.

You might have to rebuild the cases, as opposed to just `cases map (_.untypecheck)`.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Trees.scala#L1100

Comment: What do you mean by rebuild the cases. This does not work either: `cases.map{case cq"$x1 => $x2" => cq"$x1 => $x2"}`

Comment: Btw, it might be relevant to note that the "cause" for this is the unapply in the pattern match. Get rid of any unapply and the above macro works fine. Maybe I should have put more emphasis on that in the question.

Comment: Yes, that's the point of the comment in the linked code, I think. You have to deconstruct the trees with a SELECTOR_DUMMY. Or maybe there's an existing mechanism in the pattern matcher. I haven't tried yet.